# Are Sequel::Model validations only instance methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

In modern versions of ActiveRecord you can define any number of `before_validation` handlers using a simple declaration:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :do_something
  before_validation :do_something_else
end
```

Using Sequel it looks like the only way you can do this is similar to the older ActiveRecord method:

```
class MyModel < Sequel::Model
  def before_validation
    super

    do_something
    do_something_else
  end
end
```

Is there a plugin that adds the simplified declarations, or is that just how it is? The Sequel documentation doesn't paint a very clear picture. There is no `MyModel.before_validation` class method defined.

**Update:** As the answers below indicate, this behavior is not present by default. I've made a Sequel::Model plugin that fixes this called [sequel_simple_callbacks](http://github.com/tadman/sequel_simple_callbacks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian Campbell mentioned, you can use the `validation_class_methods` plugin. It's not recommended, but it is supported.  The `validation_helpers` plugin gives you similar helpers that the `validation_class_methods` plugin gives you, for use as instance methods inside the `validate` method.

Writing validations as instance methods is a better approach, IMO, which is why Sequel encourages it.  Validations are inherently an instance level activity, not a class level activity.  With the class level validations, handling things like conditional validation has to have special syntax (like `:if=>proc{}`), where you can just use normal conditional ruby statements in the instance method (such as `if`, `else`, `case`, etc.).

Obviously, if you are coming from ActiveRecord, it's a different approach.  Sequel does not attempt to clone ActiveRecord's behavior, though the two libraries operate similarly in some respects.

Comment: ActiveRecord calls them "callbacks", Sequel calls them "hooks" but they're those `after_` and `before_` class methods like `after_update` and `before_save` which are at least named the same thing in both camps. That plugin makes validations more flexible, but does not add the ActiveRecord-style methods for callbacks/hooks, just gives you finer grained control over your validation methods ActiveRecord-style.

Comment: You can use the `hook_class_methods` plugin for a similar interface for to ActiveRecord for hooks/callbacks.  I should have read your example code more closely, since that plugin would pretty much work directly for your first example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Sequel has a plugin, [`validation_class_methods`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/ValidationClassMethods/ClassMethods.html), which provide a class-method based interface for adding validations. According to [the validation documentation](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/validations_rdoc.html) it is intended only for legacy compatibility, but if you prefer that interface, it should be fine to use it.

Comment: That's for the validations themselves, which is a nice thing to have, but I'm talking about the defined "hooks": before_X, after_X which aren't covered in that plugin.

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation that allow you to add such hooks on the class level. You could write such a thing yourself, as a plugin, but I don't think they provide exactly what you're looking for, as they seem to prefer making you just define an instance method.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case. Re-defining the instance method seems like a step back to Rails 1.